# Ошибка с R в android studio

Tags: java, android

Как исправить ошибку? У меня `R` выделяется красным цветом, когда я пытаюсь сделать следующее

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Comment: наведите на R, нажмите alt+enter -> import class

Comment: @АндроидАндроид, теперь у меня выделяется красным имя xml файла, т.е. activity_main.

Comment: а он у вас есть?

Comment: @АндроидАндроид, да

Comment: Посмотрите какой именно R-файл вы импортировали? Видимо вы импортировали android.R

Comment: @Werder, да - android.R

Comment: В этом и есть ваша проблема, вы сказали активити искать лэйаут activity_main в библиотеке андроида, а его там нет, вот студия и ругается. Удалите импорт, и импортируйте alt+enter заново, и из выпадающего списка выберите R-файл вашего проекта

Answer (score 2):

Build->Clean project или Sync project попробуй в таких случаях